# Omnet++ how to subclass my own node

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have already programmed my node in omnet++. Its called SAodv here is the example code. This whole code is representing simple module behavior.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "aodvrreqmsg_m.h"
#include "aodvrrepmsg_m.h"
#include "pingmsg_m.h"
#include "self_ping_retransmit_m.h"
#include "aodvrerrmsg_m.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

struct ID_table_element
{
    std::string src_node_ip;
    double last_id;
};

struct Routing_table_element
{
    std::string destination;
    std::string next_hop;
    int hop_count;
    double dst_seq;
    int lifetime;
};

struct Ping_table_element
{
    std::string destination;
    int id;
    int received; //0 - no , 1-yes
};

class SAodv : public cSimpleModule
{
    private:
        long ping_replies_received = 0;
        long messages_sent = 0;
        long rreqs_sent = 0;
        long rreps_sent = 0;
        long rrers_sent = 0;
        long rreqs_generated = 0;
        long rreps_generated = 0;
        long rrers_generated = 0;

  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
    virtual void finish() override;
    virtual AodvRREQmsg *generateRREQ(const char* src_mac, const char* src, const char* dst, int hop_count, double rreq_id, const char* dst_ip, long dst_seq, const char* src_ip, long src_seq);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    virtual int return_host_id(const char* node_name);
    double current_rreq_id;
    long current_seq_id;
    int mobility_direction;
    std::list<ID_table_element> id_table;
    std::list<Routing_table_element> routing_table;
    std::list<Ping_table_element> ping_table;

};

Define_Module(SAodv);
```

Now i want to use functionality of this node and change only some functions. I tried with this.

```
#include "aodvrreqmsg_m.h"
#include "aodvrrepmsg_m.h"
#include "pingmsg_m.h"
#include "self_ping_retransmit_m.h"
#include "aodvrerrmsg_m.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

struct ID_table_element
{
    std::string src_node_ip;
    double last_id;
};

struct Routing_table_element
{
    std::string destination;
    std::string next_hop;
    int hop_count;
    double dst_seq;
    int lifetime;
};

struct Ping_table_element
{
    std::string destination;
    int id;
    int received; //0 - no , 1-yes
};

class AODV_rreq_attack : public SAodv
{
};

Define_Module(AODV_rreq_attack);
```

But i cant even build it got following errors:

```
cannot convert 'AODV_rreq_attack*' to 'omnetpp::cModule*' in initialization aodv_rreq_attack.cc /SimpleAodvRouting  line 45 C/C++ Problem - in Define_module row

expected class-name before '{' token    aodv_rreq_attack.cc /SimpleAodvRouting  line 42 C/C++ Problem - risght after class
```

How can I extend my existing class and override only some selected functions? Should `extends` be specified also in my NED file?

Comment: Did you actually include the original SAodv class header anywhere in your subclass header?

Comment: No, because i have only .cc file .h was not generated. Should i do it myself?

Comment: Or is there any way to generate it from .cc file by Omnet?

Comment: Simply create one yourself and put the class code into the header file and reference this header whenever you want to subclass from SAodv. Just like its done with all other classes in OMNeT++ / C++ in general.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So if i modify original SAodv.cc i have to update SAodv.h manualy so the change will also afftect subclassed Class?

Comment: There is no automatic updating whatsoever, if you change the header or the source code file, you will need to update if the changes affect the respective other file. Your header should contain the class definition and the public/protect/private member functions and variables. Your source code file should contain the actual code that does the work within the member functions. Your subclass contains the functions that you want to add or change.